# Shell script: retrieve the number at the end of the line of a url

Tags: shell, http, ubuntu, curl

http://192.168.56.101/related/content/124

Want to extract 124 from the above url using shell script

Comment: try `echo 'http://192.168.56.101/related/content/124' | grep -o "[0-9]*$"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url='http://192.168.56.101/related/content/124' ; echo ${url##*/}
```

This will extract everything after the last "/"

Answer (score 0):

This would give you some hints:

```
URL='http://192.168.56.101/related/content/124'
URL_NOPRO=${URL:7}
URL_REL=${URL_NOPRO#*/}
echo "/${URL_REL%%\?*}"
```

Or you can try this `one liner:`

```
echo 'http://192.168.56.101/related/content/124' | perl -n -e 'm{http://[^/]+(/[^?]+)};print $1'
```

Comment: `URL_NOPRO` is only correct for 4-letter protocols.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also `sed` command. It will remove everything til the last '/' character

```
url='http://192.168.56.101/related/content/124' 
number=`echo $url | sed -e 's/.*\///'`
echo "number=$number"
```